# Post a comment on a post on a group's wall

Tags: facebook, comments

So, I'm using the [fb.wall](http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall/) jQuery plugin, to display a private group's wall on my website. I've tried to use the new version, but I couldn't get it working with private groups.

My question is: How do I post a comment with the api to a post on the wall? I didn't find anything about it in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/).

But if you know any other PHP/JS solution I'm fine with that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user has granted you the `user_groups`, `read_stream` and `publish_stream` permissions, you can access the feed from the groups that user is in and add comments to the posts on their behalf.

So, with the right permissions, access:

- `/me/groups` to get a list of [groups](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/)
- `/GROUP_ID_HERE/feed` to see the current group content
- Take the [post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) ID from there
- Add the comment to the Post by making a POST request to `/POST_ID/comments`
- you'll get back the comment ID

I just tested these exact steps using the [Graph API Explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and it worked and posted the comment successfully